# How do I find all values where all rows associated with that value meet a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL that is structured as follows:

```
Name  Value1  Value2
A     .2      .3
A     .1      .05
A     .5      .3
B     .2      .4
B     .1      .08
C     .3      .4
C     .2      .5
C     .1      .3
```

How do I get all the Names where Value1 is less than Value2 for every row associated with a Name? In the example above, I would only want to pull out Name C.

I read this article: [Select in MySQL where all rows meet a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538303/select-in-mysql-where-all-rows-meet-a-condition)

but I don't think this applies to my problem, as this solution assumes you are comparing a row to fixed value.

Comment: are u using `MySql or tsql` ?

Comment: @BHouse Probably MySQL, given that the OP cites a MySQL link in the question.  But, in this particular case, the answers won't really vary that much between the two databases.

Comment: @adam please remove incorrect tags from the  question

Comment: @BHouse, the tsql tag is correct. I only referenced the MySQL article because it was the closest solution I could find. Should I still remove the tag and specify tsql in my question?

Comment: @Adam it shouldn't make a difference , check if my query still works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variant on some of the other answers, also using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN value1 >= value2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The above query asserts that each matching name group does not have any record for which `value1` is greater than or equal to `value2`.

Comment: I like this answer but I prefer the inverse having; and flag what you are looking for: sum(case when value1 < value2 then 1 else 0 end) >0. Both are valid, it just helps in my head to not have to unravel as much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having count(*) = sum(case when value1 < value2 then 1 else 0 end);
```

There are other ways to phrase this, such as:

```
select distinct name
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.value2 >= t2.value1);
```

Or:

```
select name
from t
except
select name
from t
where value2 >= value1;
```

Comment: the "other ways" don't seem to work when I tried them; though the first is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXIST` to check if the value exist in your desired condition wherein all rows by certain name have value2 greater than value1.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT  1
                FROM    TableName b
                WHERE   a.name = b.Name
                GROUP   BY b.name
                HAVING  COUNT(case when b.value1 < b.value2 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*))
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/082fd85/3).

This will display all rows for the valid `name`. However, check other answer if you only want to display distinct `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired result with `in` clause

```
declare @table table (name varchar(10), value1 float, value2 float)
insert @table
select 'A',    '0.2',     '.3'
union all
select 'A' ,   '.1',     '.05'
union all 
select 'A',    '.5',     '.3'
union all
select 'B',   '.2',     '.4'
union all
select 'B',    '.1' ,    '.08'
union all
select 'C',    '.3'  ,   '.4'
union all 
select 'C',    '.2'  ,     '.5'
union all 
select 'C' ,    '.1' ,     '.3'
```

Use In Clause where `value1<value2`

```
select * from @table where value1<value2 
and name not in ( select name from @table where value1>value2)
```